# Trigger an event (send a mail) when all the object in the relations are saved in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm developing an eCommerce in django. 
The issue is about Order and RowOrder computations:

```
class Order(Model):
    STATUS = {
        'NPAI': 'Not paid',
        'PAID': 'Paid',
        'SHIP': 'Shipped',
    }
    status = CharField(max_length=4, choices=STATUS.items(), editable=False, default='NPAI')
    cod = CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, db_index=True, editable=False)

    total_price = DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.00'), editable=False)
    vat = DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=Decimal('0.00'), editable=False)
    [...]

class RowOrder(Model):
    article = ForeignKey(Article)
    order = ForeignKey(Order)
    [...]
     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # update order
        with transaction.commit_on_success():
            order_Locked = Order.objects.select_for_update().get(id=self.order.id)
            order_Locked.total_price += self.price
            order_Locked.vat_price += self.price - self.price/(1 + order_Locked.vat/100)
            order_Locked.save()
```

As you can see, I update the values of an **order** *every time a* **roworder** *is saved*. This works well, but now I've to send an order confirm email when the order is created, but if I send the email in Order.save():

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.status == 'NPAI':
            super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            send_order_confirm(self)
```

then, rightly, the self.roworder_set in that time is empty.
I've chosen a wrong approach or actually is there anything that I can do to achieve my goal? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **akshar raaj** comments I think that I've solved my issue:

I've to trigger the event from django-admin and not in the model:

```
class OrderAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    [...]

    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        super(OrderAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
        order = formset.instance
        if order.status == 'NPAI':
            send_order_confirm(order)
```

[useful link to the django official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_formset)

clearly if I need that event from a view I can directly call send_order_confirm in the view

Answer (score 0):

You should use `post_save` on Order for this. Also, you want to send the email only when order is created, so:

```
def send_order_confirmation(sender, **kwargs):
    created = kwargs['created']
    if created:
        #logic for sending email

post_save.connect(send_order_confirmation, sender=Order)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but no, it doesn't work that way. In fact, post_save is triggered after Order.save() and at that point, don't  exist any roworder objects (yet)

Comment: Not sure, what your use case is then.Yeah, I agree that no roworder for this particular order will be available when order is created.

Comment: I'd want that the roworder objects actually exists when i send mail

Comment: Will the roworder object be created as soon as order object created? In that case you can save() both of these objects in the view and then send the mail. If not this, then can you explain the exact flow you want?

Comment: You're right man and thank to you I'm thinking at the problem in the right-way. The fact is that I'm developing an ecommerce starting by the back-office (implemented in django-admin). So currently if I do an order I do it via django-admin interface (inserting roworder with inline). Clearly the ecommerce in production will do 99% of the orders automatically but 1% of these will be issued still by django-admin. Now, when I make an order via a view, clearly I can manage the things, but when I make an order via django-admin, is there that i can do when I click save (that is, send a mail)?